# How to install ms sql on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Actually now i m using ubuntu 10.04. I need ms sql. How can i install please give a clear  idea.I ve refered so many forums but nothing give good idea.

Comment: "ms sql" usually means Microsoft SQLServer which is only supported on Windows platforms. Do you mean MySQL?

Comment: This question really belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 5):

You essentially have 3 options here.  You can try your hand with wine a program that allows you to install and use some windows programs.  Not all windows software works on wine, and I would not be surprised if ms sql didn't work on wine.  The next two are much more practical, use a virtual machine such as virtual box, or dual boot with windows.  Dual booting will give you the best performance, as you won't have to share resources.  Take your time and google these options and decide whats best for your situation.   You can always try multiple options and see which works best.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Windows VM on Ubuntu and then install SQL Server on the Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server [requires Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx). You cannot install it on Ubuntu.